# Words containing 'unimp'?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for some words which contain **unimp** in them, for example 'unimportant'. But it would be great if the word does not have negative meaning.

Comment: http://www.findtheword.info/Search.aspx?stype=contains&sword=unimp

Comment: I don't think this question fits the ELU model of one question having a right answer.

Answer (score 2):

*unimpaired
unimpassioned
unimpeachable
unimpeached
unimpeded
unimportance
unimportant
unimposing
unimpressed
unimpressible
unimpressionable
unimpressive
unimpressively
unimproved*

Comment: He only said "contains", he didn't say "begins with"...

Comment: This is what I got from **egrep "unimp" wordlist.txt**. It appears that sequence of characters only occurs at the beginning of words, and given that list, that they're all formed from the same original prefixes, and they're all negative, though not all of them are pejorative.

Comment: I added "unimplemented" and "unimpressionable", which are in the current yawl (Yet Another Word List). http://freecode.com/projects/yawl

Answer (score 2):

A search through a Scrabble word list reveals no words containing "unimp" other than those *beginning* with unimp.

Of these, the positive ones:

- unimpaired
- unimparted
- unimpeachable
- unimpeachably
- unimpeached
- unimpeded
- unimpededly
- unimpugnable

The negative, neutral and not so sure:

- unimpassioned
- unimplemented
- unimplored
- unimportance
- unimportances
- unimportant
- unimportuned
- unimposed
- unimposing
- unimpregnated
- unimpressed
- unimpressible
- unimpressionable
- unimpressive
- unimprisoned
- unimproved

Comment: +1 Nice, a _Scrabble_ dictionary. Oddly, some of these words don't turn up in my online MW or AHED editions.

Answer (score 1):

As far as *unimp-* words with non-negative meanings or connotations, there's

> **unimpeachable** : not to be called in question : exempt from liability to accusation : IRREPROACHABLE, BLAMELESS

You can add:

> **unimpaired** : not damaged or made less

There's also **unimpressible**, but according to Merriam-Webster, it has negative connotations:

> **unimpressible**: not impressible; especially : lacking in mental sensibility or responsiveness